# How to set different body background color for different pages in one css files?

Tags: css, background

I have a few pages. page1 `<body id="page1">`, page2 `<body id="page2">`, page3 `<body id="page3">` then I want write all the css rules in one css file 'style.css', set page1 background color:#000; page2 background color:#fff; page3 background color:#00f;

```
body #page1{background-color:#000;}
body #page2{background-color:#fff;}
body #page3{background-color:#00f;}
```

but it is wrong, how to write correctly? thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just remove the space (You want to specify all elements with the tag name `body` **and** the ID `page1`):

```
body#page1{background-color:#000;}
```

Comment: This is correct. To expound a bit: the rule yuli chika originally wrote, `body #page1`, means "an element with id of page1 INSIDE the body element." Removing the space makes it "body elements with and id of page1."

Answer (score 4):

```
#page1{background-color:#000;}
#page2{background-color:#fff;}
#page3{background-color:#00f;}
```

you can also write

```
body#page1{background-color:#000;}
```

butbody selector is redundant (and slower) in this case.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the non-necessity of `body` (although it looks nicer when it's there)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through jQuery also.See the below example.

```
.bg-white{
background-color: #fff;
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').addClass('bg-white');
});
```